# Electron,Spectron: how to write test cases in seperate javascript file

Tags: javascript, electron, chai, chai-as-promised, spectron

I am testing electron application use these technologies, **Spectron, Chai, chai as promised** I want to write my test cases in separate file, except all in one file.

Here's what I've tried,

```
describe("Login", function () {
    this.timeout(10000);

    //Case 1: wait for Electron window to open
    it('open window', function () {
        return app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded().getWindowCount().should.eventually.equal(1);
    });

    //Case 2: Initial Login - Empty username & Password
    it("Click on Login Without any Data", function () {
        //Wait for window to load
        return app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
            .setValue(usernametxt, "")
            .setValue(passwordtxt, "")
            .click(submitbtn)
            .getText('.notification-content')
            .should.eventually.equal("Please fill both username and password");
    });

});
```

Simply I want to write Case 1 and Case 2 into Seperate file, from Test initializing File.

Comment: You can use this documentation which provided from webdriver.io http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create two spec files with your tests separated:

```
spec1.js
spec2.js
```

Create a .js file with the following contents (test.js):

```
require('spec1')
require('spec2')
```

And in the package.json, refer to test.js in the mocha test command:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "mocha test/test.js"
}
```

considering you have a test folder.